# Trying optimize this ruby code to over array sorting/matching

Tags: arrays, ruby, performance, sorting, optimization

I have some problem here in my internship. I need to get all sequences from an array: Assuming that I have this Array `[1,2,3,4,5]`, I need to generate all sequential sub arrays like `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]`, `[4]`, `[5]`, `[1,2]`, `[2,3]`, `[3,4]`, `[4,5]`, `[1,2,3]`, `[2,3,4]`, `[3,4,5]`, `[1,2,3,4]`, `[2,3,4,5]`, `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

After this, I need to remove from this generated arrays some sub-arrays. I called this the "not allowed".

For example, if the not allowed are `[1,3]` and `[3,5]` I need to remove the sequences `[1,2,3]` (`[1,3]` is in that), `[3,4,5]` (`[3,5]` is an sub-array of), `[1,2,3,4]` (`[1,3]` iis an sub-array of), `[2,3,4,5]` (`[3,5]` is an sub-array of) and `[1,2,3,4,5]` (`[1,3]` and `[3,5]` is an sub-array of).

I did some code that is working, the problem is: **big arrays** (`n` can be `10^5`), **the code is very slow** (If you try with `n = 1000` you will see). My code is below. The not allowed are generated from `[a[i], b[i]]`.

```rb
require 'set'

def not_allowed(a, b)
  count = a.size - 1
  (0..count).map { |i| [a[i], b[i]] }
end

def combinations(n)
  combinations = []
  elements = (1..n).to_a
  elements_sequence = (0..elements.size - 1)

  elements_sequence.each do |i|
    elements_sequence.each do |j|
      next if elements[j..i].size == 0

      combinations << elements[j..i]
    end
  end
  combinations
end

def adjustCombinations(n, a, b)
  sequences = combinations(n)
  not_alloweds = not_allowed(a, b).map { |not_allowed| not_allowed if not_allowed[0] != not_allowed[1] }.compact
  final_not_alloweds = not_alloweds.map { |not_allowed|  sequences.map { |sequence| sequence if not_allowed.to_set.subset?(sequence.to_set) }.compact }.flatten(1)

  (sequences - final_not_alloweds).count
end

adjustCombinations(5, [2,1,2], [2,3,5])
```

In this example case `[1,3]` and `[2,5]` are not allowed. When not allowed are equals like `[1,1]`, `[2,2]`, `[3,3]` this is not a problem.

`n` is to identify that array goes until `5`.

**UPDATE 1: I have the limit of 9 ~ 10 seconds to run this code**

UPDATE 2: For not_alloweds **[1,3] and [2,5]**, we need remove, for example, the sequences [**1**,2,**3**], [**1**,2,**3**,4] [**2**,3,4,**5**], [**1**,**2**,**3**,4,**5**] (if you look the not_alloweds are an subsequence of the sequences listed)

**UPDATE 3: I need the number of possible allowed_sequences. In the case of:**

```
n = 5
a = [2,1,2]
b = [2,3,5]
```

Expected result is **11**

Comment: "for big arrays (n=1000) the code is very slow" How slow? My first attempt with n=1000 takes 9s. Is that too slow?

Comment: @JaredBeck well, here for n = 1000 takes more than 20 seconds to run and I have an i7 8750 CPU, `n` can be 10^5, in this case, takes more than 10 minutes running

Comment: What's the upper bound for your array size? This sort of problem suggests to me that a bitset might be the answer. Doing boolean math is way, way easier than testing individual array elements. E.g. `disallowed_pattern & entry == disallowed_pattern` means you hit a disallowed entry. This will work if you're dealing with simple numerical values. That could cut your *O(n^2)* problem down to *O(n)*.

Comment: It appears from your code that you wish to compute the *total number* of subsequences that satisfy certain conditions, not an array of those subsequences (each subsequence corresponding to a range `i..j`). Yet that is not stated as the objective and readers  who do not read through your code might assume you wish to return an array. That needs to be made clear.

Comment: @CarySwoveland i want compute the total number of subsequences that satisfy certain conditions. I will made this more clear

Comment: Actually the excluding arrays are [1,3] and [2,5]. You mean overlap like [1,3] overlaps [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4] and [2,5], overlaps [2,3,4,5] (for example)? So yes, it cant overlap. So we need remove this sequences from the possible ones.
I need the number of permited sequences

Comment: Edited the original post with an update

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the tips about stackoverflow and sorry about mess the question, i'm learning ruby, i will do better questions :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland In the example, [4,6] is not valid because **n = 5**, so the maximum number is 5. I dont know what you mean with overlaps, but invalids sequences are the ones that the subsquence [1,3] and [2,5], are present.

Comment: Ohh, I understand now. The not allowed array dont overlap itself. We just need remove the valid sequences that contain it or if it is an subsequence inside the valid array. So, if we have, for example, the [1,4] and [3,6] not alloweds, every sequence that [1,4] and [3,6] is present (exactly or is an subsquence), we need remove. For example, [3,4,5,6] we cant count because [3,6] is an subsequence of it @CarySwoveland

Comment: I'll have a revised answer for you tomorrow. I finished the coding and testing; I just have to write it up. I removed all but one of my comments on your question to clean it up. You might want to consider doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating all combinations, followed by removing what you don't need. It might be faster to only create what you actually need.

You could for example add a block to the `combinations` method that determines whether or not a combination is added to the output. This way you don't generate an unnecessary long array that need to be subtracted from later.

```
require 'set'

def combinations(n)
  combinations = []
  elements = (1..n).to_a

  elements.each_index do |i|
    (elements.length - i).times do |j|
      combination = elements[j, i + 1]
      # add the combination if no block is given, or if it evaluates to truthy
      combinations << combination if !block_given? || yield(combination)
    end
  end

  combinations
end

def adjustCombinations(n, a, b)
  not_allowed = [a, b].transpose
  not_allowed.reject! { |n1, n2| n1 == n2 }
  not_allowed.map!(&:to_set)

  combinations(n) do |combination|
    combination = combination.to_set
    not_allowed.reject { |set| set.size > combination.size }
               .none?  { |set| (set - combination).empty? }
  end
end

adjustCombinations(5, [2,1,2], [2,3,5])
#=> [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

If you only need the element count you can replace `combinations = []` with `combinations = 0` and `combinations << combination` with `combinations += 1`. That way you don't need to instantiate the whole combinations array, which saves a lot of memory with larger numbers.

Comment: I understand your answer, but [1,2] is valid because the not allowed are [2,2], [1,3] and [2,5] (a[i], b[i]), but [2,2] is not a problem, so we consider only [1,3] and [2,5] the not alloweds.

Comment: Ah, so you [`transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Array.html#method-i-transpose) the input arrays. Although the output isn't entirely the same, I hope the explanation is. It's more about the [`yield`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument) than anything else.

Comment: `[[2,1,2], [2,3,5]].transpose #=> [[2, 2], [1, 3], [2, 5]]`

Comment: I ran your code and it was very good, much better than mine. I asked someone here at my internship to see if it's good enough, but I have the limit of 9 to 10 seconds to execute the code and for large arrays it's still taking longer than that. I still can't think of another way to count all the cases, but I'm still trying here.

Comment: @Alecsander Have you also tried the `combinations += 1` from the answer? But yeah this answer is not the fasted. A faster answer involves more maths. You'll first have to calculate the total combinations, which is `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (n - 1) + n`. Then subtract the combination count possible with `not_allowed`. I've got a sort of working version, but it doesn't account for overlapping possibilities between the different given `not_allowed` options. I'll see if I can break my brain over it later.

Comment: Yes, i tried with `combinations += 1` and `transpose`. That's what I added to the code:
`not_allowed = not_allowed.transpose.reject { |n| n[0] == n[1] }.map(&:to_set)` rejected the not_alloweds that are equal, like [1,1], [2,2], [3,3] ....

`combinations += 1 if !block_given? || yield(combination)` Count the cases.

Comment: @Alecsander This is what I had so far, but since it's currently producing wrong results so I can't add it as an answer. It might give you or somebody else some inspiration though. https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/126a295ad8b002b73b80aaa7ef25c348

Answer (score 1):

The OP has defined 2-element "not allowed" arrays, `[i,j]`, `j >= i`. I find it more descriptive to refer to "not to be covered" (*NTBC*) ranges, `i..j`, `j >= i`. Given a positive integer `n` and and an array `arr` of NTBC ranges, the objective is to determine the number of ranges covered by `1..n` that cover *none* of the NTBC ranges; that is, count those ranges `i..j` for which:

```
arr.any? { |r| (i..j).cover? r } == false
```

Here and in the following, whenever I refer to a range `i..j` it is to be assumed that `i` and `j` satisfy the condition `1 <= i <= j <= n`.

I refer to two NTBC ranges `i..j` and `p..q` as *overlapping* if `i < p < q < j` or `p < i < q < j`. Below I present a very fast solution for the case where there are *no* overlapping NTBC ranges. The OP has stated that NTBC ranges can overlap, so my solution falls short of a complete answer. The problem is that the presence of overlapping ranges destroys the mathematical structure required by the combinatorial algorithm I employ. I decided to present my solution nevertheless in the hope that someone may find a way to extend my ideas to the case where NTBC ranges may overlap.

**Create `count_ranges` method**

Let's first create a method that, given integers `i` and `j`, `i <= j`, counts the number of ranges `p..q` such that `i <= p <= q <= j`; that is, for which `(i..j).cover?(p,q) #=> true`. For example,

```
(20..40).cover?(12..18) #=> false
(20..40).cover?(14..28) #=> false
(20..40).cover?(23..37) #=> true
(20..40).cover?(29..47) #=> false
(20..40).cover?(43..51) #=> false
```

See [Range#cover?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) for the case where the argument is a range. The method follows.

```
def count_ranges(i,j)
  return 0 if j < i
  n = (j-i+1)
  n**2 - (n-1)*n/2
end
```

For example:

```
count_ranges(1,4)   #=> 10
```

These would be the `10` ranges:

```
1..1, 1..2, 1..3, 1..4,
      2..2, 2..3, 2..4,
            3..3, 3..4,
                  4..4
```

Note that:

```
count_ranges(3,6)   #=> 10
```

or, more generally,

```
count_ranges(n,n+3) #=> 10
```

The rationale for the calculation performed by this method is as follows. Given the range `i..j`, `i <= j`, the number of ranges covered by this range is computed as follows.

```
n = j-i+1
n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + n-(n-1)
  = n*n - (1 + 2 +...+ n-1)
  = n*n - (n-1)*n/2
```

`n` equals the number of ranges that begin at `i` and end at `k`, where `i <= k <= j`. `n-1` equals the number of ranges that begin at `i+1` and end at `k`, `i+1 <= k <= j`, and so on. `n-(n-1) #=> 1` equals the number of ranges that begin at `i+(n-1) #=> i+(j-i+1-1) => j` and end at `k`, `j <= k <= j`.

`(1 + 2 +...+ n-1)` is the sum of an arithmetic sequence, which equals the product of the number of elements in the sequence (`n-1`) and the average value in the sequence, which equals the sum of the first and last elements (`1+(n-1) #=> n`) divided by `2`.

This method does all the work in the code below. It is important to note that the execution speed of this method is almost independent of the magnitudes of its two arguments.

**Remove redundant NTBC ranges**

Let `arr` be an array of NTBC ranges. The first step is to remove NTBC ranges that cover another NTBC range. If:

```
r1 = u..v
r2 = x..w
```

and `u <= x =< w <= v` (`r1.cover?(r2) #=> true`), `r1` is redundant and therefore can be disregarded, as any range `r` that is disqualified from the count because `r.cover?(r1) #=> true` would be disqualified by `r2` if `r1` were not present.

```
require 'set'

def remove_redundant_ranges(arr)
  set = Set.new
  a = arr.dup
  while a.any?
    r = a.shift
    set << r unless set.any? { |t| r.cover?(t) } || a.any? { |t| r.cover?(t) }
  end
  set.to_a  
end
```

For example:

```
arr = [2..4, 7..14, 8..12, 14..14, 4..5, 1..5, 9..12, 2..4]

remove_redundant_ranges(arr) 
  #=> [14..14, 4..5, 9..12, 2..4]
```

**Counting method**

```
def count_non_covering_ranges(n, arr)
  (([0..0] + remove_redundant_ranges(arr).sort_by(&:begin)) << (n+1..n+1)).
    each_cons(2).
    sum { |r1,r2| net_count(r1, r2) }
end

def net_count(r1, r2)
  r1b, r1e = endpoints(r1)
  r2b, r2e = endpoints(r2)
  count_ranges(r1b+1, r2e-1) - count_ranges(r1b+1, r1e-1)
end

def endpoints(r)
  [r.begin, r.end]
end
```

**Examples**

*Example 1*

```
n = 9
arr = [2..4, 4..5, 7..9]
```

```
count_non_covering_ranges(n, arr)
  #=> 20
```

The `20` ranges covered by `1..9` which do not cover any NTBC ranges in `arr` are as follows.

```
1..1, 1..2, 1..3,
      2..2, 2..3,
            3..3, 3..4,
                  4..4,
                        5..5, 5..6, 5..7, 5..8,
                              6..6, 6..7, 6..8,
                                    7..7, 7..8,
                                          8..8, 8..9
                                                9..9
```

*Example 2*

```
n = 12
arr = [2..4, 4..7, 9..11]
```

```
count_non_covering_ranges(n, arr)
  #=> 38
```

The `38` ranges covered by `1..12` which do not cover any NTBC ranges in `arr` are as follows.

```
1..1, 1..2, 1..3,
      2..2, 2..3,
            3..3, 3..4, 3..5, 3..6,
                  4..4, 4..5, 4..6,
                        5..5, 5..6, 5..7, 5..8, 5..9,  5..10,
                              6..6, 6..7, 6..8, 6..9,  6..10,
                                    7..7, 7..8, 7..9,  7..10,
                                          8..8, 8..9,  8..10,
                                                9..9,  9..10,
                                                      10..10, 10..11, 10..12,
                                                              11..11, 11..12,
                                                                      12..12
```

*Example 3*

```
n = 12
arr = [2..4, 6..8, 9..11]
```

```
count_non_covering_ranges(n, arr)
  #=> 34
```

The `34` ranges covered by `1..12` which do not cover any NTBC ranges in `arr` are as follows.

```
1..1, 1..2, 1..3,
      2..2, 2..3,
            3..3, 3..4, 3..5, 3..6, 3..7
                  4..4, 4..5, 4..6, 4..7
                        5..5, 5..6, 5..7,
                              6..6, 6..7,
                                    7..7, 7..8, 7..9,  7..10,
                                          8..8, 8..9,  8..10, 
                                                9..9,  9..10, 
                                                      10..10, 10..11, 10..12,
                                                              11..11, 11..12,
                                                                      12..12
```

*Example 4*

```
n = 15
arr = [2..4, 4..5, 9..12, 14..14]
```

```
count_non_covering_ranges(n, arr)
  #=> 44
```

The `44` ranges covered by `1..15` which do not cover any NTBC ranges in `arr` are as follows.

```
1..1, 1..2, 1..3,
      2..2, 2..3,
            3..3,
                  4..4,
                        5..5, 5..6, 5..7, 5..8,   5..9,  5..10,  5..11,
                              6..6, 6..7, 6..8,   6..9,  6..10,  6..11,
                                    7..7, 7..8,   7..9,  7..10,  7..11,
                                          8..8,   8..9,  8..10,  8..11,
                                                  9..9,  9..10,  9..11,
                                                        10..10, 10..11,
                                                                11..11,
                                                10..12, 10..13,
                                                11..12, 11..13,
                                                12..12, 12..13, 
                                                        13..13,
                                                                15..15
```

*Example 5*

```
n = 15
arr = [2..4, 4..5, 9..12, 14..14]
```

```
require 'time'

n = 1_000_000_000_000
m = 1_000 # number of NTBC ranges
s = 1_000 # size of each NTBC range
q = n/m
arr = m.times.map do |i|
  from = rand(i*q..(i+1)*q-1-s)
  from..from+s-1
end
arr.first(3)
  #=> [737321450..737322449, 1803846784..1803847783, 2536962375..2536963374] 
arr.last(2)
  #=> [998900666529..998900667528, 999036273747..999036274746] 

t = Time.now
x = count_non_covering_ranges(n, arr)
  #=> 585_410_016_606_600_423_738 
puts "#{(Time.now-t).round(2)} seconds"
0.24 seconds
```

**Explanation**

See [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

The first thing to notice is that the execution speed of `count_non_covering_ranges` is nearly independent of the magnitude of its first argument, `n`, and the sizes of the NTBC ranges, and is roughly proportional to the size of its second argument, `arr`, the number of NTBC ranges.

Suppose:

```
n = 14
arr = [2..5, 7..9, 10..13]
```

We first modify this to the following:

```
r1 = 0..0
r2 = 2..5
r3 = 7..9
r4 = 10..13
r5 = n+1..n+1 #=> 15..15
a = [r1, r2, r3, r4, r5]
```

We first compute:

```
c1 =  count_ranges(r1.begin+1, r2.end-1)
  #=> count_ranges(1, 4)   #=> 10
```

This is the number of ranges covered by `1..4`, none of which cover any of the NTBC's. These `10` ranges are `1..1`, `1..2`, `1..3`, `1..4`, `2..2`, `2..3`, `2..4`, `3..3`, `3..4` and `4..4`.

Next we compute:

```
c2 =  count_ranges(r2.begin+1, r3.end-1)
  #=> count_ranges(3, 8)   #=> 21

c3 =  count_ranges(r3.begin+1, r4.end-1)
  #=> count_ranges(8, 12)  #=> 15

c4 =  count_ranges(r4.begin+1, r5.end-1)
  #=> count_ranges(11, 14) #=> 10
```

Now sum these values:

```
c1 + c2 + c3 + c4
  #=> 56
```

Let's compare this with what we would compute for the total:

```
count_non_covering_ranges(n, arr)
  #=> 49
```

The discrepancy is due to the fact that we have double-counted `7` ranges:

- `c1` and `c2` both count the ranges `3..3`, `3..4` and `4..4`;
- `c2` and `c3` both count the range `8..8`; and
- `c3` and `c4` both count the ranges `11..11`, `11..12` and `12..12`.

We must therefore subtract from `49`:

```
count_ranges(r2.begin+1, r2.end-1) + count_ranges(r3.begin+1, r3.end-1) +
  count_ranges(r4.begin+1, r4.end-1)
  #=> 3 + 1 + 3 => 7
```

For convenience I also subtract out the following:

```
count_ranges(r1.begin+1, r1.end-1) + count_ranges(r5.begin+1, r5.end-1)
  #=> count_ranges(1, -1) + count_ranges(16, 14) => 0 + 0 => 0
```

This is permitted as I constructed `count_ranges` so that `count_ranges(i, j)` returns zero when `j < i`.

Answer (score 0):

> for big arrays (n=1000) the code is very slow ..
>
> - n = 1000 takes more than 20 seconds to run and I have an i7 8750 CPU
> - n == 10^5 .. takes more than 10 minutes running
> - I have the limit of 9 to 10 seconds .. for large arrays ..

## A solution using bitwise operators: n=10^4 in 83s

Here's my best effort, **with tests and benchmarks**. It's not fast enough, but I think there are **two good techniques here** that you can use, notably:

1. generating "sub arrays" with bit-shifting (`<<` in `sequential_sub_arrays`)
2. performing "omissions" via bit-masking (`&` in `omit?`)

These are not techniques I use often or well, so I present them only as a stepping stone for other people to play with.

To meet your goal ("9 to 10 seconds .. for large arrays") you may need to take these techniques and implement them in a faster language, like C or rust.

```
# Convert omissions like [1,3] into bitmasks like 0b00000101. See use in `omit?`.
def omissions_to_masks(omissions)
  omissions.map { |o|
    len = o.max
    s = o.each_with_object('0' * len) { |e, a| a[e - 1] = '1' }
    eval('0b' + s.reverse)
  }
end

# Test 1: omissions_to_masks
expected = [
  0b00000101, # [1,3]
  0b00010100  # [3,5]
]
actual = omissions_to_masks([[1,3], [3,5]])
fail unless actual == expected

# bit_subarray is an Integer, whose bits represent an array of Integers.
# For example, 0b00111001 represents the array [1,4,5,6]
def omit?(bit_subarray, masks)
  masks.any? { |o| bit_subarray & o == o }
end

def sequential_sub_arrays(n, output, omissions)
  masks = omissions_to_masks(omissions)
  1.upto(n) do |size|
    proto = 2 ** size - 1
    0.upto(n - size) do |shift|
      value = proto << shift
      unless omit?(value, masks)
        output << value
      end
    end
  end
end

# Test 2: sequential_sub_arrays
expected = [
  0b00001,
  0b00010,
  0b00100,
  0b01000,
  0b10000,
  0b00011,
  0b00110,
  0b01100,
  0b11000,
  0b01110,
]
actual = []
sequential_sub_arrays(5, actual, [[1,3], [3,5]])
fail unless expected == actual

# Benchmarking. I use a `NullArray` to discard results, 
# because n=10^4 would produce 60 GB of results and I 
# don't have enough memory.
class NullArray
  def <<(x)
    # noop
  end
end

require 'benchmark'
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  [5, 100, 1_000, 5_000, 10_000].each do |max|
    x.report { sequential_sub_arrays(max, NullArray.new, [[1,3], [3,5]]) }
  end
end
#        user     system      total        real
#    0.000034   0.000002   0.000036 (  0.000032)
#    0.002266   0.000007   0.002273 (  0.002274)
#    0.444146   0.001798   0.445944 (  0.446747)
#   14.362543   0.375005  14.737548 ( 14.765235)
#   83.235438   8.440965  91.676403 ( 92.070415)
```